# Elasticsearch synonym list with multi word values

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder if there are any Elasticsearch experts around...

Reading the elasticsearch documentation, it seems that due to the way the synonyms file is tokenized, it is really difficult (maybe even impossible) to have a synonyms list that has multi word values. Could one of you experts confirm if the following scenario is indeed impossible or if it can be realised somehow with the synonyms functionality configuration?

What I am after is as follows:

I have the following synonyms file:

word1, word2 word3, word4

I am trying to achieve the following:

1) If I search for word1, I am expecting all documents containing word1, word4 or "word2 word3".
2) If I search for "word 2 word3", I am expecting all documents containing word1, word4 or "word2 word3".

Massive thanks for your help on this in advance!

Cheers,

Olli

Answer (score 0):

We solved this on the Clientside.
So we did two searches. The first in the Synonyme Index to get all the valid synonyms for the search and then we searched the real Index with should query:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Then you have all the valid possibilities and can even expand the synonyms dynamically

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately we do not have such control over the user interface. Cheers, Olli